# Proof that a measure is a countable sum of dirac measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ with $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$. Suppose there exists $t\neq 0$ such that $|\int e^{itx}d\mu (x)|=1.$ Prove $\mu$ is a countable sum of dirac measures with coefficients.

Here's how I'm trying to go about it.

Let $f(x)=e^{itx}$.
Let $\alpha=\overline{\int f}$ that is, the conjugate of $\int f$. Since $|\int f|=1$, $|\int f|=\alpha \int f=\int \alpha f$.

Since  $\int \alpha f$ is real, we have
$|\int f|=Re\int \alpha f=\int Re(\alpha f)\leq\int|Re(\alpha f)|\leq \int|\alpha f|=\int|f|$,

but we know that, in this case, $|\int f|=\int|f|$ so all the inequalities are actually equalities.

$\int|Re(\alpha f)|= \int|\alpha f|$ implies that $Im(\alpha f)=0$ a.e., that is, $\cos^2(tx)=\sin^2(tx)$ a.e.

I'm trying to derive from it some useful implication to solve this problem, but with no progress.

Could anyone give me some direction? 
I would appreciate any comment. 
Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo. It should be $f(t) :=$ etc. and it also doesn't follow that $|f|=1$ necessarily. The statement only says *there exists*, not *for all*.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you. I corrected it (hopefully)!

Comment: Why would $\lvert \int f\rvert=\operatorname{Re} \int \alpha f$?

Comment: @tomasz Another mistake. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: Hint: Since $|e^{itx}|=1$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$, the only way to have $|\int e^{itx}d\mu (x)|=1$ for non-zero $t$ is to have all participating   $e^{itx}$ point in the same direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu)\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be the identity function. So distribution of $X$ is $\mu$ and $\int e^{itx}d\mu=E(e^{itX})$. Now
$$
E(e^{itX})=E(\cos(tX))+iE(\sin(tX)).
$$ 
So 
$$|E(e^{itx})|^2=E(\cos(tX))^2+E(\sin(tX))^2.
$$
Hence 
$$
1=E(\cos(tX))^2+E(\sin(tX))^2.
$$
But by Cauchy-Schwarz 
$$
E(\cos(tX))^2\leq E(\cos^2(tX)), \quad E(\sin(tX))^2\leq E(\sin^2(tX))
$$
and $E(\cos^2(tX))+E(\sin^2(tX))=1$. So 
$$
E(\cos(tX))^2 = E(\cos^2(tX)), \quad E(\sin(tX))^2 = E(\sin^2(tX)).
$$
So $\cos(tX)$ is degenerate. Hence $X$ is discrete. Hence $\mu$ is a weighted sum of dirac measures.

Comment: Thank you for your post. A dumb question. What is degenerate in this context? I looked it up but couldn't figure out the specific meaning in this case. It would be really helpful if you could mention where to look up.

Comment: It means distribution of $\cos(tX)$ is supported only on one point. Here is the reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution